# Linker Error when calling cc26xxware function ti_lib_timer_int_register()

Tags: contiki

I am currently working on a contiki os port for a custom platform based on the TI CC2650 chipset (and srf06-cc26xx sample plattform).
When trying to call the cc26xxware function *ti_lib_timer_int_register(GPT1_BASE, TIMER_A, trf_timer_fxn);* 
I am getting a linker error.

The exact error message is:

```
cc2650.c:(.text.trf_startClock+0x4a): undefined reference to `NOROM_TimerIntRegister'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However, other function calls from the same library (e.g. *ti_lib_timer_int_enable()*, etc.) are linked without any issues.

The function trf_timer_fxn is declared as static void trf_timer_fxn(void). Removing the static did not change anything.

I am using the latest contiki os version from github and have updated to the current cc26xxware's. Building is performed using a modified version of the sample Makefile that usually works very well.

Can anybody reproduce this behaviour? Any ideas what else I could try?

Thank you very much!

Comment: To the person that downvoted my question: I'd appreciate some feedback on how to improve the question! Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, the [answer](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/tree/master/platform/srf06-cc26xx#filename-conflicts-between-contiki-and-cc26xxware) actually lies within the README of the contiki plattform.
You have to rename the cc26xxware timer.c into driverlib-timer.c as contiki already uses a file called timer.c